# Multiple filters usage in Fullcalendar 4.0 events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

```js
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2015-05-01',
  events: [{
      title: 'Event 1',
      start: '2015-05-01',
      school: '10',
      college: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 2',
      start: '2015-05-02',
      school: '2',
      college: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 3',
      start: '2015-05-03',
      school: '1',
      college: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 4',
      start: '2015-05-04',
      school: '2',
      college: '2'
    }
  ],
  eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {

    if ($('#currentAction').val() == 'school') {
      if ($('#school_selector').val() != 'all')
        return ['all', event.school].indexOf($('#school_selector').val()) >= 0
    }

    if ($('#currentAction').val() == 'college') {
      if ($('#college_selector').val() != 'all')
        return ['all', event.college].indexOf($('#college_selector').val()) >= 0
    }
  }
});

$('#school_selector').on('change', function() {
  $('#currentAction').val('school');
  $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
})
$('#college_selector').on('change', function() {
  $('#currentAction').val('college');
  $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
})
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>



  <select id="school_selector">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">School 1</option>
    <option value="2">School 2</option>
    <option value="10">School 10</option>
  </select>
  <select id="college_selector">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">college 1</option>
    <option value="2">college 2</option>
  </select>

  <div id="mycalendar"></div>
  <span id="currentAction" name="currentAction" />
```

I have multiple filters to be applied on fullcalendar events.
Filter one is 'Status' and filter two is 'NAME'.
When I apply 'Status' filter using the logic in eventrender the month view shows only the selected 'Status' events, when I am trying to apply second filter 'NAME' with some other logic block in eventrender, it considers all events in month view irrespective of first 'Status' filter result.
The reason for this is as I wrote code in eventrender for first 'Status' filter as, if the status of any event does not matches with my selected 'Status', I just returned false, so I did not apply any hiding or removing of event from the calendar, might be this is the reason the fullcalendar considers all events are valid for subsequent filtering.
Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . We can't fix descriptions. Its like asking a mechanic to fix your car by just giving them a description of your car over the phone. First thing they will do is ask to see the car. Same with code. The description is helpful but it's not enough by itself.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, sorry for incomplete details, I will create a sample and provide that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prabha_s/tf15wLhq/30/  there are 2 filters(School/ College) select boxes. I choosed one option in 1st box,events have been filtered,then select option in 2nd box, it doesn't consider the current displaying events, where as It considers total events of fullcalendar,I can achieve the correctresults by using&&operator of two selected options from the both  boxes,but that is not the case I need, here my requirement is after filtering the events in school select box, then we select any option in college select box it should only considers the filtered events of full calendar.

Comment: The relevant code needs to be shown in the question, not just an external link. You should know that by now surely, you've asked enough questions before. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - item 1.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thank you for your guidance, Added the logic in the post, The issue is when I select 'school 10' option from school select box, it is displaying only one event, when I select one of the option in second College select box, it does not considers the available filtered events that are currently displaying on calendar, as it considers all the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are aiming for. You can test it best by selecting School 2, and then changing between College 1 and 2 (and All) and observing which events are shown and hidden.

Your problem was the "current_action" variable, which was causing only one filter to run at a time. The other `if` statements inside eventRender were also a problem because they would also stop the indexOf query (which contains the "all" option") from returning a useful result.

Once you've simplified it by removing all that noise, you can just combine the results of both the indexOf queries, and only display events which meet both conditions (i.e. they meet the criteria set by both the dropdowns).

```js
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2015-05-01',
  events: [{
      title: 'Event 1',
      start: '2015-05-01',
      school: '10',
      college: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 2',
      start: '2015-05-02',
      school: '2',
      college: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 3',
      start: '2015-05-03',
      school: '1',
      college: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event 4',
      start: '2015-05-04',
      school: '2',
      college: '2'
    }
  ],
  eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
      var school = ['all', event.school].indexOf($('#school_selector').val()) >= 0;
      var college = ['all', event.college].indexOf($('#college_selector').val()) >= 0;
      return (school && college);
  }
});

$('#school_selector').on('change', function() {
  $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
})
$('#college_selector').on('change', function() {
  $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
})
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>



  <select id="school_selector">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">School 1</option>
    <option value="2">School 2</option>
    <option value="10">School 10</option>
  </select>
  <select id="college_selector">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">College 1</option>
    <option value="2">College 2</option>
  </select>

  <div id="mycalendar"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @ADyson, yes I followed the same join condition in evenrender block, but my doubt is when we apply one filter the events are filtered and only the events which satisfied the first filter are getting displayed on calendar, when we apply the second filter on the calendar is there any way to only consider the current events which are displaying on the calendar.

Comment: Yes. My code does that. Use my demo and carry out the test I suggested above. Using the join condition isn't the only change I've made, is it? I've also removed other things which were causing a problem. I thought my description explained it clearly, but if there's something you didn't understand in what I wrote, then please mention it specifically. Or if you want the code to behave differently than I've made it behave, please detail exactly what results you expect when certain filters are applied.

Comment: Thank you for the details, I want to apply filters separately, here I am requesting a way to get the events those are currently displaying on the calendar ( means after applying first filter then for the next filter I want only the events which satisfies the first filter that is currently displaying events with out join conditions in eventrender) , I hope my request is clear but it is stupid doubt, any way thanks a lot.

Comment: "means after applying first filter then for the next filter I want only the events which satisfies the first filter "... Again, yes, that's what my code does. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Tried your code immediately after you posted, I am requesting for an alternative to get the events from the calendar such as WYSIWYG with out the condition return (school && college); in eventrender .

Comment: I literally have no idea what you mean. If you don't want the code to produce the results it does, then please give specific examples of what results it _should_ return. e.g. If I select School 2 and then also select College 2, what event(s) do you expect to be shown on the calendar? The way you have been describing it up to now, I would expect it to show Event 4, because that is the only one which school ID 2 and college ID 2. If that's not correct, then what should it be? I can't understand what you are trying to say, so please give precise examples.

Comment: ...or, are you maybe asking how to export the filtered list of events from the calendar into another variable? Even after re-reading your comments several times, I'm really not at all sure now.

Comment: When I choose 'School 10' in the first filter, on fullcalendar only one event 'Event 1' has been displayed, it's correct, later on when I choose any option from College drop down, in eventrender block before writing the logic for College filter I want only the one event 'Event 1' from full calendar as WYSIWYG , my intention is can we get what events are currently displaying on the calendar (in this case it is event 1 )

Comment: Yes,I am asking how to export the filtered list of events from the calendar into another variable

Comment: The answer you provided is very helpful, it's capable of accepting as an answer, accepted it, but the possibility I am asking is different, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok. That wasn't clear at all from your original descriptions. Anyway https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/clientEvents is what you need for that. If you notice, it has a callback function where you can put filtering logic. I expect you could apply the same logic I've used above to get the results